# cocoa iphone core-data predicate one-to-many fetchrequest

Tags: cocoa, core-data, one-to-many, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a set of data where one of the attributes (Firmware) is a one-to-many relationship.

If I want to get any records where the firmware id is 1 I can create a predicate using

```
@"(ANY Firmware.FID==1)"
```

Then I have another set of conditions that will refine the set even more using

```
(TopLevel==YES) AND (Parent>0)
```

How can I combine them or set it up so that first it filters the firmware then it filters the second condition?  Ultimately I want all of the records where Firmware.FID=1 and TopLevel==YES and Parent>0.

Thanks,
Howie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use this predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TopLevel == %@ AND Parent > %@ AND ANY Firmware.FID == %@",[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0],[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]];
```

I moved the condition on "ANY Firmware.FID" last since it is the most complex and it can be avoided if one of the other conditions has already failed.